# Symfonfy3 Cannot find class namespace

Tags: php, api, symfony, namespaces

I've just gotten into Symfony and REST APIs. I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't what.

1. Using FOSRest
2. I do use Repositories for Abstraction.
3. I don't use any ORM.

I've got a Controller. I've included the use of a repository that does the DAL Logic.

```
use GASBundle\Repository\ExpenseRespository;

// @REST\GET("/expense/{id}") 

public function idAction($id) {
  $userRepo = new ExpenseRespository();
  $dbData = $userRepo->find($id);
  return Response(json_encode($dbData));
}
```

This is the routing file:

```
API:
Type: rest
resource: "@GASBundle/Controller"
```

The error that is giving me

> [{"message":"Attempted to load class \"ExpenseRespository\" from
>   namespace \"GASBundle\Repo\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for
>   another namespace?",

Comment: Check the class name spelling 'ExpenseRespository' looks to hae an extra 'S' in the 'Re*s*pository'

Comment: I can't belive the error. Thanks for tip.